# Why won't excel let me round down in one specific circumstance?

Tags: excel, rounding

First timer here!

I have a problem that I cannot solve in Excel. In every scenario but one rounding works normally. In this unique situation, I need to round down.

Examples:

```
.65 to .6
.065 to .06
.0065 to .006
```

so on and so forth.  HOW ON EARTH CAN I DO THIS ROUNDING IN EXCEL?

I have tried all sorts of rounding and truncating functions in excel and nothing works.  I can get it to work for the specific example I am looking at but the second I add another example in it breaks.

Comment: If all you're looking to do is remove the last digit, this might be a solution: `=--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)`

Comment: [`ROUNDDOWN`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rounddown-function-2ec94c73-241f-4b01-8c6f-17e6d7968f53)?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad rounddown won't work because I don't want to round down in all other situations

Comment: Could this work for you: `=IF(ROUND(A1-0.01,1)=ROUND(A1,1),ROUND(A1,1),ROUNDDOWN(IA1,1))`? (the preceding is if you want to round to 1 decimal, you'll need to adjust the number you substract based on how many decimals you round to and how precise the original numbers are)